# Browse Title not changing with changing Locale in Browser when using input type "file"

Tags: javascript, html, input-type-file

I know this question has been asked many times and there are some hacks which can be used but those hacks involve using an image to cover the Browse button.But what I want is that the title Browse should get changed automatically when I change the locale of the Browser.
Is there any way where I can set the title of this button as per my choice and hence it gets changed as per locale of the browser.

Comment: From what i know I don't think there's any other way but to use a image,div or button to over the browse button and initiating the fileopen dialog using javascript. But i am curious to see what others have got on this !!

Comment: Hi Arun,How can I use a button as a cover?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong .. From your question .. You want to show different texts in the inputtype=file's browse button based on the page you are in . am i right .. if this is the case .. hide the file input , place your button with custom text over the file input and just capture and initiate the actions using javascript

Comment: which browser(s) are you testing this with? Are you getting the same behaviour with all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: This happens with all the browsers and is not limited to a particular one.

Comment: What I want is that If I change the locale of my browser to german or japanese or any non english language, Browse should be displayed in that language

Comment: Check this out , this might be a good start ..http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/language-decl/